# How to remove item from array knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout.js library. I am trying to using knockout `arrayRemoveItem` utility function but it seems that its not working. Here is my code :

**JS**

```
function VM()
{
  this.Items = [{id:'1', name:'A'}, 
                {id:'2', name:'B'}, 
                {id:'3', name:'C'}, 
                {id:'4', name:'D'}
               ];

  this.Delete = function(){
    console.log(this.Items);          //before removing

    ko.utils.arrayRemoveItem(this.Items, function(item){
      return item.id == '3';
    });

    console.log(this.Items);          //after removing
  };
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsbin.com/emiqej/1/edit)

If you check the console after pressing delete button, item 3 is not removing from array. What i am missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `arrayRemoveItem` takes the items to be removed as the second argument like `ko.utils.arrayRemoveItem(array, itemToRemove)`, so you need to first find the object and pass it to `arrayRemoveItem`.

Try

```
function VM()
{
  this.Items = [{id:'1', name:'A'}, 
                {id:'2', name:'B'}, 
                {id:'3', name:'C'}, 
                {id:'4', name:'D'}
               ];

  this.Delete = function(){

    var item;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.Items, function(v) {
      if(v.id == '3'){
        item = v;
      }
    });

    console.log(this.Items);
    ko.utils.arrayRemoveItem(this.Items, item);
    console.log(this.Items);
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/emiqej/2/edit)

Comment: This removed the item from the array for me, but it did not trigger the observable, when I changed the arrayRemoveItem to the remove function on the array, self.availableSecondScreens.remove(itemToDelete) - the observable was triggered

Comment: Trying arrayRemoveItem and .remove still leaves a blank row in my table.